# Научить gitk определять кодировку текстовых файлов

Tags: git, кодировка

Имеется проект на C# под *Visual Studio*, размещенный в git-репозитории. Исходные файлы по умолчанию имеют кодировку UTF-8, при этом имеется несколько текстовых файлов *win1251*.

При просмотре изменений средствами `gitk` из комплекта [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/downloads) файлы *win1251*, содержащие кириллицу отображались корректно. А вот для файлов с кодом `*.cs` (UTF-8) в этой части рисовались каракули.

После установки кодировки по умолчанию для *GUI* части `git` командой:

> ```
> git config --global gui.encoding utf-8
> ```

файлы `*.cs` стали отображаться нормально. Но проблема переехала в обычные текстовые файлы. В связи с этим вопрос:

Можно ли в `gitk` одновременно корректно отображать файлы в различных кодировках?

Comment: а может их конвертировать в нормальную кодировку?

Comment: @KoVadim я так и сделал, но при этом при просмотре старых ревизий всё равно остаются проблемы.